# Save New Record Of Product (Duplicate) when Add this to Category

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, code-first, updates

In EF Code First I have two tables (product - categories)
relation is many to many
i create a product and add to category
(im using autofac)

```
Product _product = null;
using (var builder = EngienContext.container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
     var _productService = builder.Resolve<IProductService>();
     _product = _productService.InsertProduct(new Product()
           {
                NameEn = nameEn,
                ShortDescription = shortDescription,
                FullDescription = fullDescription,
                DateTimeCreate = DateTime.Now,
                CreatedOnUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
                ActiveStatus = true,
                AdminLockReadOnly = false,
                Deleted = false,
            });

    var _categoriesService = builder.Resolve<ICategoriesService>();
    Categories _category = _categoriesService.GetCategoryByGuid(_categoryGuid);
    _category.Products.Add(_product);
   _categoriesService.UpdateCategory(_category);

}
```

but when i add product to _category.products create new record of product on product table and add id of new record to mapping table . . .

My Table Valuse When Update:

```
product table:

ID         Name         ShortDescription
1:         test      test table id must be 1
2:         test      test table id must be 1
3:

Category table:

ID        Name         Description
1:      categor1      test category1
2:

product_category_mapping table:

ProductID     CategoryID   
  2                1
```

but i want:

```
product table:

ID         Name         ShortDescription
1:         test      test table id must be 1
2: 

Category table:

ID        Name         Description
1:      categor1      test category1
2:

product_category_mapping table:

ProductID     CategoryID   
  1                1
```

my update method in service:

```
    public virtual void UpdateCategory(Categories Category)
    {
        if (Category == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Category");
        }

        _categoryRepository.Update(Category);
    }
```

my update method in Repository:

```
    public TEntity Update(TEntity item)
    {
        return _context.Update(item);
    }
```

my update method in DbContext:

```
public T Update<T>(T item) where T : class
    {

            if (item == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
            var entry = this.Entry(item);
            if (entry != null) 
            {
                entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(item);
            }
            else
            {
                this.Attach(item);
            }
            this.SaveChanges();
    }
```

my relation on mapping:

```
            this.HasMany(p => p.Categories)
            .WithMany(c => c.Products)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("Product_Category_Mapping"));
```

Comment: `but when i add product to _category.products create new record of product on product table and add id of new record to mapping table` Is this the expected behavior but it didn't happen? Could you please rephrase your statement. What is the error (if any)? What is the expected behavior? What did actually happen?

Comment: @Yuliam Chandra , when i _productService.InsertProduct(...) save new product in product table and when _category.Products.Add(_product); _categoriesService.UpdateCategory(_category); expected behavior:create new record only in mapping table and don't create new record in product table again

Comment: Could you please show the `_categoriesService.UpdateCategory(_category);` method ?  You can edit your question btw, there is an edit button under the tags.

Comment: @YuliamChandra , edited plus table records

Comment: @YuliamChandra , i think my problem solution is into how use autofac or my wrong in the using(...){...} , please help me

Comment: I think you need to attach / change the state to unchange of the product in the Update method, `Entry(item.Product).State = EntityState.Unchanged;`

Comment: @YuliamChandra , I tried but this code in update method make error: "providerIncompatileExeption was unhandeled by user code"

Comment: hmm I think it's not related to the new code, my point was when updating an entity and the entity has reference that is not attached to the context, it will be considered as new item

Comment: @YuliamChandra , how attach to context? , can you show me a simple (sry, im starter)

Comment: you can read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx)

Comment: @YuliamChandra , i tried bud my Update method in DbContext class is generic (each class can use this method) so i cant access item.product ... , i see a project don't used autofac and update with my way . . . , but im with autofac have problem ...

Comment: @YuliamChandra , when ichanged _category.products.add(_product); _categoryService.UpdateCategory(_category) to "_product.categories.add(_category); _productService.UpdateProduct(_product); "this error generated: exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects. , this is not for autofac? , because i resolve to service . . .